# Invalid identifier in hbase shell

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to run a mapreduce job which delete hbase rows. I'm using the following command to run the MR job.

> export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol.jar: /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml; hadoop jar Rows.jar DeleteHBaseRows table_name pattern

I din't set the configuration settings inside the application. That's why

> /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml

is in the command. Job runs fine and complete the task. But i'm getting a error. How to get rid of that error?

Error is

> -bash: export: `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add the hbase-site.xml in the export command. Remove that and try again.

Comment: if i remove hbase-site.xml from the command i have to reset the configurations manually in the program(zookeeper quorum)